# Using case instead of IF ELSE to change WHERE clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I am trying to build a query in which where clause slightly changes depending on an external variable and I came up with the below script

```
IF(@threshold='N')

  select  min_price
  ,       s.customization_type
  ,       gii.brand
  ,       gii.item_flag
  from   item_info gii
  ,      style s
  ,      categories gpc  
  where  isnull(@ordered,getdate()) between gpc.start_date and isnull(gpc.end_date, dateadd(day, 1, getdate()))
  and    gii.segment1 = s.style_number   
  and    gpc.line_of_business_category = 'AAA'
  and    gii.inventory_item_id = @v_item_id;

ELSE 
      select  min_price
  ,       s.customization_type
  ,       gii.brand
  ,       gii.item_flag
  from   item_info gii
  ,      style s
  ,      categories gpc  
  where  isnull(@ordered,getdate()) between gpc.start_date and isnull(gpc.end_date, dateadd(day, 1, getdate()))
  and    gii.segment1 = s.style_number   
  and    gpc.line_of_business_category = 'BBB'
  and    gii.inventory_item_id = @v_item_id;
```

But, I feel like the above query is not clean though it gives the desired results. Is there a better way I can optimized this query like using CASE WHEN?

Comment: note my answer with explicit join as it makes me wonder if you have your join condition on categories correct as there is no direct link to your other 2 tables which means it is cross joined to the other results as limited by your conditions

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, you need to only change this line:

```
gpc.line_of_business_category = 'AAA'
```

to

```
gpc.line_of_business_category = CASE 
                                   WHEN @threshold='N' THEN 'AAA' 
                                   ELSE 'BBB'
                                END
```

If you use SQL Server 2012 or newer, then `IIF` is another alternative:

```
gpc.line_of_business_category = IIF(@threshold='N', 'AAA', 'BBB')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use a `case` expression:

```
select  min_price
  ,       s.customization_type
  ,       gii.brand
  ,       gii.item_flag
  from   item_info gii
  ,      style s
  ,      categories gpc  
  where  isnull(@ordered,getdate()) between gpc.start_date and isnull(gpc.end_date, dateadd(day, 1, getdate()))
  and    gii.segment1 = s.style_number   
  and    gpc.line_of_business_category = case when @threshold='N' then 'AAA' else 'BBB' end
  and    gii.inventory_item_id = @v_item_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  select  min_price
  ,       s.customization_type
  ,       gii.brand
  ,       gii.item_flag
  from   item_info gii
  ,      style s
  ,      categories gpc  
  where  isnull(@ordered,getdate()) between gpc.start_date and isnull(gpc.end_date, dateadd(day, 1, getdate()))
  and    gii.segment1 = s.style_number   
  and    gii.inventory_item_id = @v_item_id;

  and    gpc.line_of_business_category = (CASE WHEN @threshold='N' THEN 'AAA' ELSE 'BBB' END)
```

But you should use explicit join syntax!

When using Explicit Join syntax it makes your intentions clearer to others when debugging your code:

```
select
    min_price
    ,s.customization_type
    ,gii.brand
    ,gii.item_flag
from 
    item_info gii
    INNER JOIN style s
    ON gii.segment1 = s.style_number
    INNER JOIN categories gpc
    ON isnull(@ordered,getdate()) between gpc.start_date and isnull(gpc.end_date, dateadd(day, 1, getdate()))
    and gpc.line_of_business_category = (CASE WHEN @threshold='N' THEN 'AAA' ELSE 'BBB' END)
WHERE
    gii.inventory_item_id = @v_item_id;
```

Also it starts to show you when you might have a relationship problem such as might be the case of your categories gpc.  I see that table is not directly related to 1 of the other tables but rather you are selecting categories that are then cross joined i sthat what you intended?

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below:

```
where gpc.line_of_business = case when @threshold='N' then 'AAA' else 'BBB' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a CASE statement in your query, like below, with modifying your query as little as possible:

```
select min_price
    , s.customization_type
    , gii.brand
    , gii.item_flag
from   item_info gii
    , style s
    , categories gpc  
where isnull(@ordered,getdate()) 
    between gpc.start_date and isnull(gpc.end_date, dateadd(day, 1, getdate()))
    and gii.segment1 = s.style_number   
    and 1 = CASE 
             WHEN @threshold='N' AND gpc.line_of_business_category = 'AAA'
                 THEN 1
             WHEN @threshold <> 'N' AND gpc.line_of_business_category = 'BBB'
                 THEN 1
          ELSE 0
      END
and gii.inventory_item_id = @v_item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
  and ( (@threshold ='N' AND gpc.line_of_business_category = 'AAA')
     or (@threshold<>'N' AND gpc.line_of_business_category = 'BBB') )
```

The complete query would be

```
select  min_price
  ,       s.customization_type
  ,       gii.brand
  ,       gii.item_flag
  from   item_info gii
  ,      style s
  ,      categories gpc  
  where  isnull(@ordered,getdate()) between gpc.start_date and isnull(gpc.end_date, dateadd(day, 1, getdate()))
  and    gii.segment1 = s.style_number   
  and ( (@threshold ='N' AND gpc.line_of_business_category = 'AAA')
     or (@threshold<>'N' AND gpc.line_of_business_category = 'BBB') )
  and    gii.inventory_item_id = @v_item_id;
```